# MS PowerBI - Excluding certains rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula, powerbi-desktop, directquery

I need to create a measure (DirectQuery mode) in order to calculate the number of rows that have the same values for the field [OriginType] excluding the ones that comes from the same parents. Following an example:

**Parents**

- Parent: A
- Parent: B
- Parent: C

**Details**

- Id: 1, Parent: A, OriginType: Italy
- Id: 2, Parent: B, OriginType: Italy
- Id: 3, Parent: C, OriginType: Italy
- Id: 4, Parent: B, OriginType: Italy

My representation would be:

- Parent A, Value: 3
- Parent B: Value: 2
- Parent C: Value 3

So, I need to exclude in the calculation for each parents, the details who had the same parents. How can achieve that using PowerBI Dax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR ThisParent =
    MIN( Table1[Parent] )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS( FILTER( ALL( Table1 ), Table1[Parent] <> ThisParent ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but there is a side effect: I have a certain number of slicer, and with ALL statement they are ignored. It's not the expected behaviour for my report: If I put a filter, this filter must be applied to the CountRows. What can I do?

Comment: Change `ALL` to `ALLSELECTED`.

Comment: Yes, I tried but there is a still one little problem: if I select as slicer filter a Parent, for Example Parent A, the value calculated will be 0 (because of the filters applied). I think I need Allselected but excluding one filter (the filter by parent)

Comment: I don't understand. If you filter on a given Parent, then the resulting table contains only that Parent. As such, quite naturally the number of rows within that filtered table which contains a Parent other than that Parent will be zero.

Comment: It works, but I have problems with subset of data. It seems that It cannot group the data: please see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72583375/powerbi-allselected-problem-when-multiple-rows-are-involved